# deleting tabs which names contain the same symbol

Tags: excel, vba

I get an extraction from SAP where for each tab there is a sister tab with the same name followed by a +. Example - `PL1516` and `PL1516+`. The latter tab hasn't got anything and I just want to delete them. I tried this macro but it's not working.

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteSheets()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sht.Name = "*+*" Then
            Sht.Delete
        End If
    Next Sht
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the Like operator to do wildcard comparisons.

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteSheets()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sht.Name Like "*+*" Then
            Sht.Delete
        End If
    Next Sht
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to change this line `If Sht.Name = "*+*" Then` with `If InStr(Sht.Name, "+") > 0 Then`. It should work.

Comment: @ThomasInzina Does the comment refer to me or to Fabi?

Comment: OMG @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 ...I am so sorry I should have know better.  I read it on my phone.  Apologies!!